# Get URL parameter and prefill form field

Tags: javascript

This is how the raw HTML of my form (email) field:

```html
<input type="text" id="FormField_EmailAddress" name="email" value="" size="40">
```

Now I want to prefill this field based on the URL parameter `email` like for example `mydomain.com/page/?email=my@email.com` should prefill `my@email.com`.

By just using a script in the header or footer of that page.

Is that possible and can anybody share a way how to do it?

PS As a total beginner I tried:

```html
<script>
  var url_string = window.location.href;
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var email = url.searchParams.get("email") ? url.searchParams.get("email") : '';
  document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value = email;
</script>
```

but it won't work...

Comment: log and see if the DOM can find your input or not
if you some how code write you code in codepen or something and share it, we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it, this is the code that made it work:

```html
<script>
    const url = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
    const email = urlParams.get('email');
    document.getElementById('FormField_EmailAddress').value = email;
</script>
```